# Display Photo library image using FILE_URI on cordova-plugin-camera

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I use the cordova-plugin-camera to ask user to choose an image from PHOTOLIBRARY.
I am testing it using an Android

The options I pass to the camera are:

```
options: {
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
            }
```

Then I on success call back I get the following URI:

```
content://media/external/images/media/14555
```

But when I try to use it to display on the html as:

```
<img src="content://media/external/images/media/14555"/>
```

It doesn't work and shows this message

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

I have tried everything and I can't get the image to show.
Just one more thing I cannot use DATA_URL on the camera plugin because I need to access the actual file.

Answer (score 1):

It response as 404 because in the context of the app the uri is irrelevant as the webview could not resolve the uri  , what would work is u need to import the file using some file API plugin and then only could it work.Hope it helps.

Comment: It helps. Sort of. I found that if I copy the photo to the app directory using cordova-plugin-filetransfer, then I can get a valid Url. But this is more of workaround than a solution. For me a solution would be to have a way to convert the content:// URI (from the camera plugin) into a valid URL usable on the webview directly.

Answer (score 0):

i have implemented this using File API plugin of cordova ,

Here is the link https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <!--
        Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
            https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
        Some notes:
            * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->

        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
                <button style="width:30%;" onclick="pickImage()">Clean Data</button>
                <p id="lastPhoto"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function pickImage(){
                var lastPhotoContainer = document.getElementById("lastPhoto");
                var doc= document.getElementBy
                window.imagePicker.getPictures(
                function(results) {
                    console.log(results);
                        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        var imageUri=results[i];
                        console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
                        lastPhotoContainer.innerHTML = "<img src='" + imageUri + "' style='width: 75%;' />";
                        }
                    }, function (error) {
                        console.log('Error: ' + error);
                }
            );
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```